# How to echo command output to end of existing line in Linux?

Tags: linux, echo

I am trying to automate the building of a config file and most of what I need can do done via a straight echo 'text here' >> myfile.conf

What I am having trouble with is appending the output of a command to the last line in the file.

My last working command is `echo 'masternodeprivatekey=' >> myfile.conf`

My next command is `./wallet-cli masternode genkey &>> myfile.conf`

I need to have the masternode key generated to be included on the same line as masternodeprivatekey= so that the line will end up as this - 
masternodeprivatekey=abcd13def456ghi789

Can this be done?

I have seen ppl suggest adding /c to the end of the echo command or -n to the end of the line however these don't work, they just add those characters to the end and still post the output of `./wallet-cli masternode genkey &>> myfile.conf` on the next line.

Is it possible to do what I want? I'm pretty sure I could echo the output to two different temp files and then combine them, but is there an easier way?

Comment: Try using `printf` instead of `echo`. It won't output any end-of-line characters unless you tell it to.

Comment: Yep, that's it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per  Mark Plotnick's suggestion, the use of printf instead of echo works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use echo with option -n , it do not output the trailing newline

```
echo -n 'masternodeprivatekey=' >> myfile.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

In sed, you can adress the last line with $

```
echo 'masternodeprivatekey=' >> myfile.conf
sed -i -r "$ s/(.*)/\1$(($RANDOM%100000))/" myfile.con
```

Check, whether your sed has -i and -r parameters. This worked with GNU-sed.

Since I don't know ./wallet-cli, I used something else in $(...) instead, to perform a command which generates output. So for you, it might be

```
sed -i -r "$ s/(.*)/\1$(./wallet-cli masternode genkey)" myfile.con
```

Since you seem to know before, that you will add something after the equal sign, why don't you do:

```
echo "masternodeprivatekey=$(./wallet-cli masternode genkey)" >> myfile.con
```